# Disable show response document in hierarchy for browser

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus, domino-designer-eclipse

I have a view of lotus notes and web browser. I have enabled show response documents and both notes and web browser showing response documents. Notes are for Admin view while web browser for employee view. So I want to create Admin can view all response document on notes but the employee cannot view response document on a web browser.

Below here my view for notes.

[image: Lotus]

Below here my view for a web browser.

[image: web]

My question is, can I disable show response document just for a web browser?
It means, my notes still showing response document but my browser will not showing response document. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why don't you create a second view for the web browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create two views: one for Notes users  (hidden for web users ) and response hierarchy disabled and vice versa one for the web users which is hidden for notes Users with response hierarchy enabled.